# Applying jquery deferred to an existing async callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to implement the code below using jquery deferred. I need to be able to have access to the returned contacts data outside the callback scope.

```
gigya.socialize.getContacts({callback: getContacts_callback });

function getContacts_callback(response) {
  return response;
}
```

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A promise should be returned by `getContacts` not a callback.

Comment: `gigya.socialize.getContacts` is an API invocation I'm implementing in my code and I want to do the implementation using jquery deferred (a.k.a Promise) pattern